# How to set value if nullable int is null

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have nullable int in the the model, Is that possible to set the value to some value if get null as the input otherwise set the incoming value as it is.

I tried below

```
public class MyRequest
    {
        private int? _quantity;

        public MyRequest()
        {
            Quantity = 1;
        }

        public int? Quantity
        {
            get => _quantity;
            set => _quantity = _quantity.IsNullOrDefault() ? Quantity : value;
        }
```

It always gives NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return default value if there is no value for `Quantity`, you could try

```
public class MyRequest
{
    const int defaultQuantity = 1;
    private int? _quantity;

    public int? Quantity
    {
        get => _quantity.HasValue ? _quantity : defaultQuantity;
        set => _quantity = value;
    }
}
```